# When CNN padding is disabled, network doesn't learn

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, torchvision, semantic-segmentation

I’m working on an unsupervised segmentation pipeline which involves first learning a SLIC segmentation with the CNN.

This works as expected when all layers in the network use padding, however, for reasons specific to this pipeline, I would like to not use any padding. Without padding, it seems that the network has trouble learning the very simple SLIC segmentation (which is essentially just a k-means of the pixels in LABXY space, and should be more than learnable by the network).

Note: the input to the network is an image with RGB and XY channels.

Here’s an example SLIC segmentation (the ground truth for the network):

[image: SLIC]

Here's an example of the network's progression with padding on:
[image: Good progression]

And here's an example of the network's progression with padding off:
[image: Bad progression]

As you can see, with padding, the model gradually converges to the ground truth, whereas with padding off, the segmentations are much noisier and eventually collapse to just 2 classes rather than 10.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here?

I've tried replacing the network with both a random forest and a simple linear classifier and it works as expected, so it shouldn't be an issue of learnability/separability.

Am I encountering some weird edge case bug? Is there a difference in differentiability? Although padding offers spatial information, given that the network receives X and Y channels in addition to RGB, this shouldn't be an issue, right?

Are there experiments I could run to further debug this?

Comment: The main reason why you want to use padding in CNN is to align and preserve the spatial dimension of the image features. Do you still get the same size output after you remove all padding? I can't tell without our code, but I assume you messed up some spatial alignment while removing padding.